# python3 import modules from different projects

Tags: python-3.x

```
├── GitHub
│   └── git_start.py
├── automation
│   ├── Docker
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   └── requirements.txt
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── config.py
│   └── test.py
```

I want to import **git_start** module(has it's own configuration) from **test.py**.
I tried everything, always get:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Maybe try to add an `__init__.py` file in the `GitHub` folder to make it a python package. Then, in `test.py`, start with `from .GitHub import git_start` (notice the dot), or `from ..GitHub import git_start` (two dots)

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: All folders are valid Python packages (specifically, [implicit namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)) in modern Python; you don't need `__init__.py`. Problem is that if your working directory is the parent of both `GitHub` and `automation`, those are unrelated packages; `automation.test` can't use relative imports to get `GitHub.git_start`. If `automation` is the working directory, `GitHub` isn't even a visible package for absolute imports.

Comment: Yes @ShadowRanger - maybe copy `git_start.py` to wherever installed packages are kept something like `envs/env/lib/python3.x` ?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: I mean, the correct solution is to install it properly with an appropriate `setup.py` so absolute imports find it (and don't use relative imports when it's not actually part of the same package). For simple test cases, you might manually modify `sys.path` (or even hackier, tweak the definition of `__package__` on the script), as demonstrated in some of the answers on the duplicate.